# Importing Excel Data into Database with Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, excel, spring-mvc

I am developing a website that stores data in a mysql database. One of the user of the website wishes to record data for the website in an excel spreadsheet. I intend to develop a solution that consist of three parts:

1. A controller class that saves the uploaded excel spreadsheet into a directory in the server.
2. A service layer that read the saved excel spreadsheet from the directory using apache POI. 3. JPA to record data in the excel spreadsheet into the mysql database.

Is this a good pattern for the intended solution ? Has anyone implemented a similar solution ?

Comment: I dont really understand your requirements.  Is the excel spreadhseet meant to be another way to get data into the database?  Or is it meant to be a replacement for the database?

Comment: @Solubris the excel spreadsheet is meant to be another way to get data into the database. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds reasonable.

- See if the user would upload a csv file instead of xls file, as this will be easier to handle.
- try to stream upload directly to disk.  If you store it in memory, then large uploads will cause out of memory error for jvm.